# MariaBD + Fedora 24 + TokuDB

Tags: linux, mariadb, tokudb

It seems that TokuDB is not available in Fedora 24 + MariaDB 10.1.17.

```
2016-09-23 18:17:56 140514451392704 [ERROR] TokuDB is not initialized because jemalloc is not loaded
```

I have jemalloc and jemalloc-devel installed

My `/etc/my.cnf/tokudb.cnf`

```
plugin-load=ha_tokudb
```

Moreover, SELinux is disabled in /etc/selinux/config

```
[root@localhost giuseppe]# sestatus
SELinux status:                 disabled
```

Comment: Can you post the output of `sestatus` ?

Comment: SELinux is disabled

Comment: Once you disable selinux, did you restart your system, right?

Comment: No I did not, because I never did in *nix systems. I will try.

Comment: Can you pldd and see if jemalloc was properly preloaded? TokuDB is simply responding to the ability to find the mallctl symbol.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use always official Repos. The Repos installed by default on Linux distros usually are not good.

In my case:

```
[mariadb]
name = MariaDB
baseurl = http://yum.mariadb.org/10.1/fedora24-amd64
gpgkey=https://yum.mariadb.org/RPM-GPG-KEY-MariaDB
gpgcheck=1
```

is ther right one to use. Then

```
dnf install MariaDB
```